# IOS get 10 object from MutableArray

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsarray

I have a `NSMutableArray *allObject`, my `allObject` have 22 objects inside.

And now I want to get 10 objects when I click button More.

I am using:

```
NSArray *arrrTemp = [arrObject subarrayWithRange:NSMakeRange(from_index, 10)];
```

1st, I got 10 object from `allObject`

2nd, I got 10 next object from `allObject`

It's OK.

But, 3rd: It's crash app. I think  `subarrayWithRange:NSMakeRange(from_index, 10)` ---> 10 is problem.

How to I can resolve this problem?

Comment: You can't hardcode a length of 10 in the `NSMakeRange`. You need to check how many objects are left.

Comment: my `allObject` have 22 object and I am using subarrayWithRange to arrrTemp, How to I can check how many objects are left.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to check if there are at least 10 objects left.

```
NSInteger length = MIN(10, arrObject.count - from_index);
NSRange range = NSMakeRange(from_index, length);
NSArray *arrrTemp = [arrObject subarrayWithRange:range];
```